# Execute ng-include when a button is clicked - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to execute a `ng-include` and show the content only after a button is clicked. I tried to use the `ng-if` directive and show the div when the `ng-model` is `true`, but his value is not changed in the `myFunction`function.

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div ng-if='include==true' ng-include='"path"'></div>
    <input type="button" ng-click='myFuntion()'/>
</div>

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.include = false;
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
        $scope.include = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: ng-if='include'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your `ng-click` function. `myFuntion` should be `myFunction`. You can also just use `ng-if='include'` instead of `ng-if='include==true'`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.include = false;
     $scope.myFunction = function(){
        $scope.include = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-if='include'>Clicked</div>
  <input type="button" ng-click='myFunction()'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create a function that change the variable path for a valid one, no need to do a ng-if

```js
$scope.myFunction = function(newPath){
      $scope.path = newPath;
}
```

```html
<div ng-include="path"></div>
<input ng-click="myFunction('path/to/file.html')" type="button />"
```